# WinRT, Use ListView to display page / UIElements

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

Good evening everyone,

I am currently developing a WinRT-App for my personal use which is supposed to

a) show a "first use / elementary settings" - dialogue and

b) contain many different settings, too much to display on a settings-charm.

So I was thinking that the ideal way to handle both of those use cases would be something like MS has done it with the "PC-Settings" in Windows:

On the left side of the page, there are several topics that may contain (in the "initial settings"-process) the first steps to set up the app and in the "settings" case may contain different settings grouped under each topic.

I guess that displaying the topics on the left is done by creating a ListView where each item is title of the topic - but, and here's my question - how is the right side of (let's say the "PC-Settings"-Page in Win8.x) filled with all those UIElements?

I would be glad if someone could perhaps just give me a hint for a technique or a keyword to look after.

Many thanks in advance

Adrian

Comment: All the right hand side content will be inside a grid with visibility set to "Collapsed". When the corresponding listViewItem is clicked/tapped on the left hand side, you set the visibility to "Visible" for the item you want to show and visibility="collapsed" for everything else.

Comment: Thank you Chris for your help! To be honest, I could have thought of this, but it would have never come to my mind. This approach seems... well, loading a huge page just to show a small percentage of it...

But hey, it seems possible to go that way, so: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use clever visibility settings to only show the items you want based on the left hand side item selected. Let us know if you need any help with the code

Comment: Having a first look, I think I'm good with the code. Thank you again for your help!